# Column index not changing after dragging columns in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using JTable for displaying the information. After rendering the information if I drag the columns to reorder them, the information is displayed in the same fashion in the session. But when I try to capture the changes by checking the column names by iterating the column names, the sequence is same as the older one. Why is the latest view not available from the API?

Comment: The view and the model are completely distinct. Changing the order of the columns should not effect the model.

Answer (score 9):

As commented by Hovercraft Full Of Eels, the column indices in the view change independently of the column indices in the model. [`JTable`'s JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) has this to say about it:

> By default, columns may be rearranged in the `JTable` so that the view's columns appear in a different order to the columns in the model. This does not affect the implementation of the model at all: when the columns are reordered, the `JTable` maintains the new order of the columns internally and converts its column indices before querying the model.

`JTable` offers the methods [`convertColumnIndexToModel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToModel(int)) and [`convertColumnIndexToView()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToView(int)) that you can use to translate column numbers from one to the other. You can use these to figure out if (and how) the columns were rearranged.

To be notified of column changes as they happen, use a `TableColumnModelListener`:

```
myTable.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener( new TableColumnModelListener() {
    //etc.
} );
```

Comment: Is there any way in JDK 1.5, to apply the changes from the view to model?

Comment: Support for converting columns indexes has existed for a long time. JDK6 added support for converting row indexes because sorting/filtering support was added.